# Alembic: Get SQL output from schema comparison within script

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I would like to compare the current db schema with my current model.
While `compare_metadata` gives a nice list of the upgrade operations required, I would also like to print out the associated SQL statements (similar to the offline `alembic upgrade head --sql` command, but without actually generating a migration script file before).

```
from alembic.autogenerate import compare_metadata
from alembic.migration import MigrationContext
from myapp import models
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("db_url...")
diff_list = compare_metadata(
    MigrationContext.configure(engine.connect()),
    models.meta.metadata
)
```

Maybe the SQL statements can somehow be generated using the `produce_migrations` api command which returns a `MigrationScript` object and is used as an input for the `compare_metadata` command (see http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/autogenerate.html#customizing-revision). Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can generate the SQL statements because they can be different depending on the DB engine you are using but you can generate the SQL Alchemy statements for this:

```
from alembic.migration import MigrationContext
from myapp import models
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("db_url...")

mc = MigrationContext.configure(engine.connect())
diff_list = compare_metadata(mc, models.meta.metadata) # not needed for this
migrations = produce_migrations(mc, models.meta.metadata) # we need this instead
sqlalchemy_statements = render_python_code(migrations.upgrade_ops))

print sqlalchemy_statements # just to see the result
```